Force vba createtextfile with Big5 encode in Windows (CR LF)?
I used this code to create a txt file with Big5 encode (Traditional Chinese).
Since I wanted to use OpenTextFile to continue processing this txt fi I discovered that due to some uncontrollable factors, the file I generated using CreateTextFile was created to Macintosh format on Windows, which caused OpenTextFile to be unable to process the txt file.
But when I open this file with notepad++, it showed Macintosh (CR).
I really don't know why my VBA code will create a file in Macintosh (CR) format on Windows PC?
With (CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"))
  If .FileExists(logFile) Then
    Msgbox "File Exist"
  Else 
    Set WSO = FSO.CreateTextFile(logFile,8, False)
    Msgbox "File Created" 
    WSO.Close
  End If 
End With

Can you help me to force vba CreaTetextFile with Big5 encode in Windows (CR LF)?
Or is there another way to use OpenTextFile with Macintosh (CR)?
Since OpenTextFile only has ANSI or Unicode format.


.txt files can have a BOM to specify UTF encoding, but there's nothing like that for Big5 (that in aware of). This encoding is usually "guessed" by the editor reading the file. If you are opposing the newly created file (and it's empty) it will guess badly. Try writing some data to the file making sure you use the correct line endings etc and see what it says.

You should be able to use ADODB.Stream to write and read Big5 encoded text

The only difference between Mac and Windows format text files are the line endings. Opening a Mac formatted file works fine on Windows; it just doesn't display properly, because it all appears as a single line of text rather than individual lines. It's hard to say what your actual problem might be, as your code does not write to the file at all, you don't show any code that opens that file, you don't explain what unable to process the file means specifically, and you don't describe a problem at all other than that vague unable to process.

I found the first newline character is the key, vbCrLf: Windows; vbCr: Macintosh; vbLf: Unix. Link

Yes, that's what I said in the first sentence of my comment above.
